# Why does my minecraft render only show hands?

Tags: rendering

I downloaded a Minecraft rig, got two skins from online and made it look like they were fighting each other. It was supposed to look like this.[image]

But when I try to render it, it looks like this.Why does it do this? [image]

Comment: Have a look to the top right part of your first image above, in the outliner. Some objects are unset for rendering (grayed camera icon on the right part).

Comment: @lemon I got a diamond axe and two arrows back, but the rest are still gone.

Comment: You should upload your file. Please use this link to do it: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I would check your render layers, and see if you happen to have multiple. Many times what will happen is that the last render layer that actually got rendered will be the only one that shows up in the Image/UV editor window. Another related thought is that you have a compositor setup, and not all render layers make it through to the final composite, so you get left with something that lacks your full intent for render. It might not seem likely, but it may just so happen that what you are seeing is the parts of your scene that co-exist on another layer.